# Прорисовка графиков на javascript

Tags: график, ajax, javascript

Доброго времени суток! Решил немного поэкспериментировать с графиками на js. В качестве отправной точки этого исследования-опыта, решил использовать библиотеку Raphaël. Вот график какой получается с использованием статических данных в таблице h[ttp://raphaeljs.com/analytics.html](http://raphaeljs.com/analytics.html). Исходя из этого примера я модифицировал формирование графика, сделал его чтобы он черех ajax загружал из базы данные таблицы и потом выводил их на экран. Но в итоге получил ошибки в консоли:

1) Error: Problem parsing d="V231.5V231.5V231.5V231.5V231.5V231.5V231.5V231.5V231.5" в файле raphael.js.

2)Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'concat' of undefined в файле analytics.js.

Проверял данные получаемые через ajax, они корректные, тоесть структура таблицы строится как надо... но почему-то не отображаются. Если меняю опять на статические данные в теге таблицы, то ошибки в консоли исчезают и график начинает отображаться. Кто работал с библиотекой Raphaël, скажите там вообще можно динамические данные заливать в таблицу, а потом по ходу выводить их? Или проблема не в этом?

Comment: Может проблема в том, что данные через Ajax и построение происходят уже после того, как raphael начал свою работу?

Comment: Попробуйте d3.js - это очень продвинутая и крутая библиотека для визуализации данных. http://d3js.org/

Comment: Выкладывайте на jsfiddle, ajax замокируйте